# DataArray deletes Attributes in simple computation

Tags: python-xarray

I've noticed that if you have a xArray DatarArray and perform simple(!) calculations on it the Attributes get 'deleted'.

Example:

```
example            = xr.DataArray(np.array([1,2,3]), attrs={'one':1})
without_Attributes = example*3
```

On the other side, if you use numpy specific functions (e.g. .round(x), ..) the Attributes remain. Is there a reasonable explanation for this? And is there a way to multiply the DataArray without loosing its attributes?

Comment: A related gotcha: each DataArray in a Dataset can have its own `.attrs`,
`dset.attrs` `dset.A.attrs` and `dset.B.attrs` all different. (What's `dset[["A", "B"]].attrs` ?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the xarray docs on ["what is your approach to metadata?"](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/getting-started-guide/faq.html#what-is-your-approach-to-metadata):

> We are firm believers in the power of labeled data! In addition to dimensions and coordinates, xarray supports arbitrary metadata in the form of global (`Dataset`) and variable specific (`DataArray`) attributes (`attrs`).
>
> Automatic interpretation of labels is powerful but also reduces flexibility. With xarray, we draw a firm line between labels that the library understands (`dims` and `coords`) and labels for users and user code (`attrs`). For example, we do not automatically interpret and enforce units or [CF conventions](http://cfconventions.org/latest.html). (An exception is serialization to and from netCDF files.)
>
> An implication of this choice is that we do not propagate `attrs` through most operations unless explicitly flagged (some methods have a `keep_attrs` option, and there is a global flag for setting this to be always True or False). Similarly, xarray does not check for conflicts between `attrs` when combining arrays and datasets, unless explicitly requested with the option `compat='identical'`. The guiding principle is that metadata should not be allowed to get in the way.

You can set global options in xarray with [`xr.set_options`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.set_options.html#xarray.set_options):

```py
In [14]: xr.set_options(keep_attrs=True)
Out[14]: <xarray.core.options.set_options at 0x133ef58e0>
```

Now, attributes are preserved

```py
In [15]: example * 3
Out[15]:
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 3)>
array([3, 6, 9])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0
Attributes:
    one:      1
```

Note that xarray does not do anything "smart" with these attributes, which is why the default behavior is to drop them in computation. For example, a simple example with units shows how setting `keep_attrs=True` can go off the rails:

```
In [17]: dist = xr.DataArray(np.array([1,2,3]), attrs={'units': 'm'})
    ...: dist
Out[17]:
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 3)>
array([1, 2, 3])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0
Attributes:
    units:    m

In [18]: rate = xr.DataArray(np.array([2, 2, 2]), attrs={'units': 'm/s'})
    ...: rate
Out[18]:
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 3)>
array([2, 2, 2])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0
Attributes:
    units:    m/s

In [19]: dist / rate
Out[19]:
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 3)>
array([0.5, 1. , 1.5])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0
Attributes:
    units:    m
```

If you want to explicitly handle units in computation with xarray, have a look at [pint-xarray](https://pint-xarray.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which is an effort to integrate the [pint project](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)'s explicit unit handling with xarray. This project is experimental and the API is not stable, but there has been considerable work lately by both the pint-xarray crew and xarray's core team to move in the same direction so I don't expect this coordination to go away.

#### Workaround (or maybe the best of all worlds?)

Note that since `Dataset` and `DataArray` attributes are simply dictionaries, preserving them is easy:

```py
In [22]: result = example * 3
    ...: result.attrs.update(example.attrs)

In [23]: result
Out[23]:
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 3)>
array([3, 6, 9])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0
Attributes:
    one:      1
```

You can even work with them independently of the DataArray or Dataset:

```py
In [25]: ds = xr.open_dataset('my_well_documented_file.nc')

In [26]: source_attrs = ds.attrs

In [23]: result = xr.Dataset({'new_var': ds.varname * 3})

In [24]: result.attrs.update(
    ...:     # custom new attrs
    ...:     method='multiplied varname by 3',
    ...:     updated=pd.Timestamp.now(tz='US/Pacific').strftime('%c'),
    ...:     # carry forward attrs from input file
    ...:     **{source_attrs[k] for k in ['author', 'contact']},
    ...: )
```

So the approach I generally take is to explicitly copy over the attributes I want *at the end of computation*. And, if desired, you can handle units explicitly with xarray-pint and then carry forward other metadata as a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to put the calculations that should keep the attributes into a local context:

```
# Compute weighted time-averages keeping units and other attributes
with xr.set_options(keep_attrs=True):
    ds = (ds * weights).mean("time")
```

This way, there's no need to change the configuration globally, so calculations in other places will not have unexpected side effects regarding attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have a Xarray Dataset `ds` like this:

**xarray.Dataset**

*Dimensions:*

```
time: 43830 lon: 135 lat: 129
```

*Coordinates:*

```
time  (time)  datetime64[ns]   1901-01-01 ... 2020-12-31
lon   (lon)   float64          66.5 66.75 67.0 ... 99.75 100.0
lat   (lat)   float64          6.5 6.75 7.0 ... 38.0 38.25 38.5
```

*Data variables:*

```
rf    (time, lat, lon)    float32    dask.array<chunksize=(365, 129, 135), meta=np.ndarray>
```

*Attributes:*

```
CDI : Climate Data Interface version 2.0.0rc1 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)
Conventions : CF-1.6
```

***and from this dataset you want to delete the attribute named CDI***

then you may use `del ds.attrs['CDI']` before exporting/saving the dataset into NetCDF file.

Comment: the question was about how to *preserve* attributes during computations. if you have a different question, feel free to ask a new one :)